# Cant validate children json-schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm working on a json schema like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "title": "Layout",
  "description": "The layout created by the user",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "stdAttribute": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["attributeName","attributeValue"],
      "properties": {
        "attributeValue": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "attributeName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "stdItem": {
      "type": "object",
      "required" : ["stdType","stdAttributes"],
      "properties": {
        "stdType": {
          "enum": [
            "CONTAINER",
            "TEXT",
            "TEXTAREA",
            "BUTTON",
            "LABEL",
            "IMAGE",
            "MARCIMAGE",
            "DATA",
            "SELECT",
            "TABLE"
          ]
        },
        "stdAttributes": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/stdAttribute"
          },
          "minItems": 1
        },
        "children": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/stdItem"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "properties":{
    "stdItem":{ "$ref": "#/definitions/stdItem" }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to validate the following json with the above scheme:

```
{
  "stdItem": {
    "stdType": "CONTAINER",
    "stdAttributes": [
      {
        "attributeName": "ola",
        "attributeValue": "teste"
      }
    ],
    "children": [
      {
        "stdItem": {
          "stdType": "TEXT",
          "stdAttributes": [
            {
              "attributeName": "ola",
              "attributeValue": "teste"
            }
          ],
          "children": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error telling me that the require attributes **stdType** and **stdAttributes** are missing for the path stdItem/children/0. As you can see the attributes are there , they are not missing.

I tried to change the order fo the attributes but still doesnt work. I keep getting the following error:

> --- BEGIN MESSAGES --- error: object has missing required properties (["stdAttributes","stdType"])
>       level: "error"
>       schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/definitions/stdItem"}
>       instance: {"pointer":"/stdItem/children/0"}
>       domain: "validation"
>       keyword: "required"
>       required: ["stdAttributes","stdType"]
>       missing: ["stdAttributes","stdType"]
>   ---  END MESSAGES  ---

Could anyone point me for what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the "children" property you are saying it's a "stdItem" , so it expects there to have the stdAttributes and stdType properties. Instead what you have in your json is a "stdItem" property that is of stdItem type.
So, you are missing the declaration of that property (stdItem) in your schema.

This schema will validate your json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "title": "Layout",
  "description": "The layout created by the user",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "stdAttribute": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["attributeName","attributeValue"],
      "properties": {
        "attributeValue": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "attributeName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "stdItem": {
      "type": "object",
      "required" : ["stdType","stdAttributes"],
      "properties": {
        "stdType": {
          "enum": [
            "CONTAINER",
            "TEXT",
            "TEXTAREA",
            "BUTTON",
            "LABEL",
            "IMAGE",
            "MARCIMAGE",
            "DATA",
            "SELECT",
            "TABLE"
          ]
        },
        "stdAttributes": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/stdAttribute"
          },
          "minItems": 1
        },
        "children": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "stdItem": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stdItem" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "properties":{
    "stdItem": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stdItem" }
  }    
}
```

Notice that I'm adding an object to the *item* specification of "children" that has a "stdItem" property.
(I didn't declare it as required but you might want to add that)